# How to "ignore" template parameters for hashmap?

Tags: c++, templates, unordered-map

Coming from a non statically typed language I sometimes struggle with type constrains.

I am looking for a way to store all my objects in a hashmap. The problem is, that the parent class uses templates as some children classes return different size and type of arrays.

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class Module {
 public:
  virtual std::array<T, Size> getValues() = 0;
};

class SwitchModule : public Module<bool, 2> {
  std::array<bool, 2> getValues() override;
};

class TemperatureModule : public Module<float, 4> {
  std::array<float, 4> getValues() override;
};
```

This all works fine, until I want to add all my `SwitchModule`s and `TemperatureModule`s to a hash map. As I have to use the base class for the hash map the compiler expects me to provide T and Size. This does not work:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, Module> modulesMap;
```

Is there a clever workaround how to save `SwitchModule` and `TemperatureModule` in an `unordered_map`? Thank you.

Comment: You want to be able to store any `Module<T,Value>` in the map?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I am trying to do. Maybe I should change the title.

Comment: If you _only_ need to be able to store `SwitchModule` and `TemperatureModule`, you could use an `std::variant`. If you want to be able to store arbitrary instantiations of `Module`, it's trickier.

Comment: `SwitchModule` and `TemperatureModule` is just a simple example I really want so save all type of Modules in the map. But thank you for the hint.

Comment: You're going to need `std::variant` or `std::any` then.  Containers in C++ hold homogenous objects, but different instantiations of a class template generates a heterogenous set of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a base class and store pointers to that in your map:

```
class ModuleBase {
public:
    virtual ~ModuleBase() = default;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class Module : public ModuleBase {
 public:
  virtual std::array<T, Size> getValues() = 0;
};
```

```
#include <memory>

// ...

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ModuleBase>> modulesMap;

    modulesMap.emplace("foo", std::make_unique<SwitchModule>());
    modulesMap.emplace("bar", std::make_unique<TemperatureModule>());
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to the `std::any` approach suggested by NathanOliver? This way I still have to cast `modulesMap.find("foo")` to `SwitchModule` before being able to call `getValues`. I thought there would be a way to call `getValues` for every object in the map.

Comment: @HennyKo Yes, it's similar and no you can't get `getValues` as a `virtual` in `MoudleBase` since the different `getValues` return different types. You can use `std::visit` like with `std::variant` though, or `dynamic_cast`, but ithere will still be a little manual work.

Comment: ... on the upside: If you do have functions that have a common interface, you can add those to `ModuleBase` as `virtual return_type function() = 0;` and override them in your concrete `*Module` classes and you can at least use those member functions without having to inspect anything.

Comment: Okay, thank you I think I understand. This way I still have the guaranty that all my Modules have the same interface as they are still subclasses of Module. I will test this out and then accept the answer, but I think this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @HennyKo You're welcome! Hope it works out!

Comment: I still have problems understanding how I can call getValues without having to cast to the specific type. If I understand it right for `std::visit` I need a `std::variant`. But this does not work `std::variant<SwitchModule *, TemperatureModule *> modules_variant = modulesMap.find("foo")->second;` adding a `dynamic_cast` would work but this would be a big if else statement if I have multiple Modules.

Comment: @HennyKo If you use a variant, then it should probably be `std::variant<SwitchModule, TemperatureModule>` (no pointers). [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/cx1cEM)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding this. I thought I could `find("foo")` and use `std::visit` to call `getValues()`. This did not work for me the only way I got it working was using `std::variant` with `dynamic_cast` as shown above.

Comment: @HennyKo Sure you can use `*find()`, `operator[]()` or `at()` on your `map` and then `visit` the result: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/hY5oYc)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I tough I could use the `ModuleBase` class, so I do not have to create a `std::variant`. And directly visit the pointer in my `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ModuleBase>>`.

Comment: @HennyKo Aha, ok, no if you use the `ModuleBase` / pointer approach you'll have to `dynamic_cast` (I think - I can't think of a way around it right now anyway). [example](https://godbolt.org/z/56zrW6)